# recaptcha on IE9 interferes with focus on inputfields

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, recaptcha

I'm having problems with the new recaptcha in IE9 (the one that checks if you're a robot by asking you to click). On IE9, after i have interacted with it (clicking on it), i can not seem to get correct focus on other inputfields elsewhere in the site, such as textareas and text-inputfields. When hovering above them, i do get a 'text-edit' cursor, but clicking doesn't give me any focus on the textfield.

I can get the textfield to get focus by tabbing, and once i do that, the mouse-interaction seems fine again. Still, this is currently a major bug in a website that i am developing and was hoping someone can clarify what's going on exactly.